# mysql database that can be accessed over a vpn?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, phpmyadmin, wampserver

I have 2 computers. Both with w7 as os. I have installed wampserver on one of them.
I have mysql database on wampserver.
Then I have made a vb.net program to connect to mysql database. I have put the program on both computers.
What I want to do is for those two programs to see the same database that is on one computer. For them to be able to add, delete, update that 1 database. 
How do I do that? How do I network the mysql database? Do I also have to install wampserver on the other computer?
What do I do? Please enlighten me.

Comment: i tried googling and I found this stuff, which I can't understand:http://www.nairaland.com/nigeria/topic-127119.0.html

Comment: did you try to connect to your other host? just connect? I dunno what vb use for this, but it must have mysql_connect equivalent. Or your question's just "how to use mysql from vb?"

Comment: No, the program can connect in wamp server where wampserver is installed. I just don't know how to connect it if wampserver is to be accessed on another computer on the lan.

Comment: whats wrong with phpmyadmin?  i see you tagged it but never mentioned anything about it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL is a database management system which will respond to ODBC (and equivalent) connections.  Get the name of your computer that is running the MySQL database, and go to http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql to find an appropriate connection string to use in the  System.Data.OleDBConnection connection string.

Comment: yeah, I already know that. I already have the program. Do I have to install connector.net to the 2nd computer which doesn't have wamp server installed to make this work?

Comment: Yes - the original WAMP server aleady has the required stuff (it came with MySQL), but the 2nd computer needs to have the interface driver (i.e.  Connector/Net) to handle the communication between .NET and MySQL

Comment: I already installed connector/net to the 2nd computer(w/c does not have wampserver installed)I also opened port 80 for both tcp and udp. In the 1st computer(w/wampserveer). Do I also need to open port 80 on the 2nd pc?what do I do next?